# Assigning parts of the file names to variables in bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash

I have a list of files in a folder for which I'm trying to build a list in the .json file in a very specific manner. Basically taking the first, second and the third parts of the file names, assigning variables to them and then passing them through.

File names:

```
a_test_1-aws.xml
b_test_2-aws.xml
a_stage_3-az.xml
c_prod_1-az.xml
```

Example of the record in .json file:

```
{"name":"$a | $b - $c", "value":"/root/environment/$d"}
```

How it should look like:

```
{"name":"a | test_1 - aws", "value":"/root/environment/a_test_1-aws.xml"},
{"name":"b | test_2 - aws", "value":"/root/environment/b_test_2-aws.xml"},
{"name":"a | stage_3 - az", "value":"/root/environment/a_stage_3-az.xml"},
{"name":"c | prod_1 - az", "value":"/root/environment/c_prod_1-az.xml"}
```

Where:

```
$a = a/b/c (anything that goes before "_" sign)
$b = test/stage/prod (anything that goes before the "-" sign)
$c = aws/az (anything that goes before ".xml")
$d = "a_test_1-aws.xml" (the .xml file name itself)
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

Separating the strings into the variables `a, b, c, d` is straight-forwarding using bash *parameter expansion* with substring removal. The parameter expansions `${var#pattern}` trims from the left though 1st occurrence of `pattern`, `${var##pattern}` trims from left through last occurrence of `pattern`. The expansion using `%` and `%%` work the same from the right.

Putting that to use in a short script to separate all names in your file, you would have:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r d || [ -n "$d" ]; do
    a="${d%%_*}"    ## trim from right though leftmost "_"
    b="${d%-*}"     ## trim from right through rightmost "-"
    b="${b#*_}"     ## trim from left through leftmost "_"
    c="${d%.*}"     ## trim from right through rightmost "."
    c="${c##*-}"    ## trim from left trough rightmost "-"
    printf "\na: %s\nb: %s\nc: %s\nd: %s\n" "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
done < "$1"
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your `.xml` filenames in the file `names` you would have:

```
$ bash splitnames.sh names

a: a
b: test_1
c: aws
d: a_test_1-aws.xml

a: b
b: test_2
c: aws
d: b_test_2-aws.xml

a: a
b: stage_3
c: az
d: a_stage_3-az.xml

a: c
b: prod_1
c: az
d: c_prod_1-az.xml
```

After you separate the parts of the file, rather than putting them back together with bash, you may be better served with a utility that is `.json` aware and can validate the result. `jq` is a tool that is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all xml filenames in the directory, and split the variables in each line. then add the generated result to a json_file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# template
JSON_STRING='{"name":"%s","value":"%s"},\n'

for file in $(ls *xml); do
  A=$(echo $file | cut -d "_" -f1)
  B=$(echo $file | cut -d "_" -f2-3 | cut -d '-' -f1)
  C=$(echo $file | cut -d "-" -f2   | cut -d "." -f1)
  D=$(echo $file)
  # using readlink to get the full path
  printf "$JSON_STRING" "$A | $B - $C" "$(readlink -f $D)" >> json_file
done
# removing extra comma
truncate -s-2 json_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like the output to be JSON objects then using JSON aware tools would be the best approach.
[Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) and its [EXPath File Module](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#modulefile) could easily do what you want:

```
xidel -s -e '
  file:list(.) ! {
    "name":replace(.,"(.)_(.+?)-(.+?)\..+","$1 | $2 - $3"),
    "value":file:current-dir()||.
  }
' --printed-json-format=compact
{"name": "a | stage_3 - az", "value": "/root/environment/a_stage_3-az.xml"}
{"name": "a | test_1 - aws", "value": "/root/environment/a_test_1-aws.xml"}
{"name": "b | test_2 - aws", "value": "/root/environment/b_test_2-aws.xml"}
{"name": "c | prod_1 - az", "value": "/root/environment/c_prod_1-az.xml"}
```

You could leave out `--printed-json-format=compact` if you want the output to be pretty.